# Pandas pivot to explode columns and fill values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a Pandas dataframe like so

```
movie, week, sales
-----, ----, ------
1,    1,     100
...
1,    52,    200 
2,    1,     500,
...
```

What I actually want it to look like is

```
movie, week_1, ... week_52, 
1,     1,          200
2,     1,          500
```

So what's effectively happened is there is now one row per movie and one column per week and the value of `df[movie, week]` equals the sales of that movie on that week.

I've tried `df.transpose()` and `df.pivot(columns=['week', 'sales'])` but neither is accomplishing the intended effect.

What the Pandas way to do this?

Comment: Try: `df.pivot(*df).add_prefix('week_').reset_index()` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73060100/19123103) for more info.